# How to merge cells in a table in PHPPresentation

Tags: php, powerpoint, phppresentation

I'm trying to merge cells in a table using PHPPresentation, but i don't find any method to do it, how I can do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is relatively old but the answer can help others.
To merge cells using PHPPresentation, we can rely on the following methods:

setRowSpan() and setColSpan() of the Cell class.

Example:

```
$cell = $row->nextCell();
$cell->setColSpan(3);
```